# Modify JavaScript object property from array to string

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object where one of the properties is an array. I want to modify that object to create an almost identical object, except that one property is a String instead.

Looks like the [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method can be used to change an array to a String (e.g., `console.log(elements.join('-'))`).

But how do I create a new object that's identical to the old object, but with one property different (i.e., a string instead of an array)?

For example, I have this object, carOriginal:

```
{
  "make": "Ford",
  "model": "F150",
  "features": [
    "windows",
    "seatbelts"
  ]
}
```

... and from that I want to create this object, carNew:

```
{
  "make": "Chevy",
  "model": "Tahoe",
  "features": "windows,seatbelts"
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to keep the original variable as well as create a new object in its own right, and not just overwrite the existing object, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using ES6 you can destructure the original and add new features value :

```js
const data = {
  "make": "Ford",
  "model": "F150",
  "features": [
    "windows",
    "seatbelts"
  ]
}


const other = {...data, features: data.features.join()}

console.log(other)
```

Comment: I don't think object spread syntax was added until later in ES2018. ES2015 only supported iterable spread and rest syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the name of the property you have to check every value to see if it is an array:

```
function subJoin(obj) {
    for (let prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (Array.isArray(obj[prop])) {
                obj[prop] = obj[prop].join(',');
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}


let input = {
    "make": "Ford",
    "model": "F150",
    "features": [
       "windows",
       "seatbelts"
    ]
}

let output = subJoin(input);
console.log(output); /// -->  { "make": "Chevy", "model": "Tahoe", "features": "windows,seatbelts" }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const obj = {
  "make": "3",
  "model": "2019-07-17",
  "features": [
    "windows",
    "seatbelts"
  ]
}

const result  =  Object.assign({},obj, {features: obj.features.join()});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object rest and spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax) to collect the rest of the keys in a separate shallow copy that the modified property will be assigned to:

```js
const carOriginal = {
  "make": "Ford",
  "model": "F150",
  "features": [
    "windows",
    "seatbelts"
  ]
};

function transform ({ features, ...keys }) {
  return { ...keys, features: features.join() };
}

const carNew = transform(carOriginal);

console.log(carNew);
```